# Kafka. Why 3 node?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm studying kafka and I see that a lot of articles about it are talking about kafka cluster with 3 nodes. And I'm curious why 3 nodes?

Do we have something technically specific about this number ?

Comment: Nothing recommends three. It could just as easily be two brokers. You could also make a topic replication factor 5 or even higher.

Answer (score 2):

This is all about high availability, the recommended replication factor for Kafka is 3, meaning that you are going to have 3 replicas for every piece of data sent to your cluster. If you have only 1 node, and that node crashes or has HW issues such as disk issues, probably you will lose all your data, as opposed to have healthy replicas on the other 2 nodes.

Here there are some additional explanations about it as well [Kafka replicas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61474336/should-we-run-a-kafka-node-with-3-replicas-or-3-kafka-nodes-with-1-replica)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons it's about electing the leader. One of the algorithms for electing a leader is Raft algorithm https://raft.github.io/ it will elect a new leader only when the major of brokers (n (alive) + 1 / 2 > all / 2) agree on one value. Long story short. If we have 3 brokers it's guaranteed that we will survive one failure. If there will be 2 brokers and one broker fails another broker will not be able to elect itself.

P.S. I'm not sure if kafka using the raft algorithm now for electing a leader (older versions used zookeeper). But I'm just writing an interesting case with electing leaders in distributed systems and if they use Raft so why it should be minimum 3.